# How to check two models ID whitout nested loop?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

My problem is the nested loop of my template... I use it to check if my model `sitio.id_sitio` has an equivalent ID with another model `comprobante.id_sitio` with a Foreign Key and then print A if one result is found and B if none

The conditional if work fine but I don't want the nested loop print multiple times.

If one result is found I want to break the cycle and print the HTML only one time, like `<a href=""> Checkouts </a>` 
Else if the result doesn't exist in the records at the end of the for I want to print `<p>No payments</p>`

I don't know if I have to write a query in the views.py or if I have to do something else in the templates...
Is there a correct way to do this?

---

This is my code:

Models.py

```
class Comprobante(models.Model):
        id_sitio = models.ForeignKey('Sitio', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_sitio', blank=True, null=True)

class Sitio(models.Model):
        id_sitio = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
        sitio = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.sitio
```

Views.py

```
def topsitios(request):
    sitio = Sitio.objects.all()[0:100]
    comprobante = Comprobante.objects.all()[0:100]

    context = {'sitio': sitio, 'comprobante': comprobante}

    return render(request, "sitio_ptc/topsitios.html", context)
```

Template.html

```
{% block content %}

{% for s in sitio %}
<tr>
<th scope="row">  {{ forloop.counter }}</th>
<td> {{ s.sitio }} </td>

<td>
{% for c in comprobante %}
{% if s.id_sitio == c.id_sitio_id %}
<a href="">Checkouts</a>
{% else %}
<p>no payments</p>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</td> 

</tr> 
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way of doing this is to use Django ORM to access a model's relationship. In the for-loop of each `sitio`, you can check if any related `comprobante` exists by `{% if s.comprobante_set.all %}`

For better performance, you would also need to prefetch related `comprobante` records by `Sitio.objects.prefetch_related('comprobante_set').all()`. This way you won't suffer from N+1 query problem.

Comment: This work for me, thanks very much!
If someone is searching for more information about prefetch_related here is a link: [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution would be:

```
{% if c.id_sitio_id == s.id_sitio %}
```

Because `Comprobante.id_sitio` is a foreign key related to a model with a custom primary key, so `c.id_sitio_id` (`_id` is a suffix added by Django that keeps the value of primary key, that is usually `id`-field in most cases) stores the value of `Sitio.id_sitio`.

But I would refactor your code to make it clearer and more flexible like this:

```
# models.py
class Comprobante(models.Model):
    sitio = models.ForeignKey('Sitio', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)

class Sitio(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

# in the template
...
{% if s.id == c.sitio_id %}
...
```

Comment: I had a error typing when posting but i edit with c.id_sitio_id now, the loop problem is now solved but thanks anyway for making my code cleaner, i will fix it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the related name attribute in `Comprobante`class

```py
class Comprobante(models.Model):
    id_sitio = models.ForeignKey(
        'Sitio', 
        models.DO_NOTHING, 
        related_name='comprobantes',
        db_column='id_sitio', blank=True, null=True)
```

once a related_name is set, you can check with it in your template

```html
{% block content %}
    {% for s in sitio %}
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">  {{ forloop.counter }}</th>
        <td> {{ s.sitio }} </td>
        <td>
        {% if s.comprobantes %}
            {# Hay un comprobante para el sitio #}
            <a href="">Checkouts</a>
        {% else %}
            <p>no payments</p>
        {% endif %}
        </td> 
    </tr> 
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried this but it did not work, It always go to checkout, even with id null in the db. Anyways the answer from Tianissimo work good for me. Thanks you.